# delete topic-messages in Apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm testing the working of kafka-topics but I don´t undestand how the deletion works.

I have created a simple topic with

```
retention.ms = 60000
```

and

```
segment.ms = 60000
```

and

```
cleanup.policy=delete.
```

After this I created a producer and I sent some messages.
A consumer receive the messages without problems.
But I expect that, after one minute, if a repeat the consumer, it doesn't show the messages because they must have been deleted. But this behaviour doesn't occur.

If I create a query in ksql it's the same. The messages always appear.

I think that I don't understand how the deletion works.

Example:

1) Topic

```
./kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test -- 
  replication-factor 2 --partitions 1 --config "cleanup.policy=delete" -- 
  config "delete.retention.ms=60000" --config "segment.ms=60000"
```

2) producer

```
./kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list broker:29092 --topic test-- 
  property parse.key=true --property key.schema='{"type":"long"}' --property 
  "key.separator=:" --property value.schema='{"type": "record","name": 
  "ppp","namespace": "test.topic","fields": [{"name": "id","type": "long"}]}'
```

3) messages from producer

```
1:{"id": 1}
 2:{"id": 2}
 4:{"id": 4}
 5:{"id": 5}
```

4) Consumer

```
  ./kafka-avro-console-consumer \
    --bootstrap-server broker:29092 \
    --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
    --topic test--from-beginning --property print.key=true
```

The consumer shows the four messages.

But I expect that If I run the consumer again after one minute (I have waited more time too, even hours) the messages don´t show because the retention.ms and segment.ms are one minute.

When messages are actually deleted?

Comment: use retention.ms in place of delete.retention.ms while creating topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `retention.ms` as mentioned by Ajay Srivastava above using `kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic test --config retention.ms=60000` and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Another important think to know in deletion process in Kafka is `log segment file`:

Topics are divided into partitions right? This is what allows parallelism, scale etc..

Each partition is divided into `log segments files`. Why? Because Kafka writes data to Disk right...? we don't want to it keep the entire `topic` / `partition` in 1 huge file, but split it into smaller files (segments)..

Breaking data into smaller files has many advantages, don't really related to the question. Can read more [here](https://thehoard.blog/how-kafkas-storage-internals-work-3a29b02e026)

The key thing to notice here is:

Retention policy is looking on the log semgnet's file time stamp.

> "Retention by time is performed by examining the last modified
> time (mtime) on each log segment file on disk. Under normal clus‐
> ter operations, this is the time that the log segment was closed, and
> represents the timestamp of the last message in the file"

(From [Kafka-definitive Guide](https://book.huihoo.com/pdf/confluent-kafka-definitive-guide-complete.pdf), page 26)

#### Version [0.10.1.0](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_10_1_breaking)

> The log retention time is no longer based on last modified time of the log segments. Instead it will be based on the largest timestamp of the messages in a log segment.

Which means it looks only on **closed** log segment files.
Make sure your 'segment' [config](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html) params are right..

Comment: This is very interesting. What I undestand is that with this that the two key parameters to control the deletion process are retention.ms and segment.ms. For example, if I want the messages are deleted in three days, I should set rentention.ms and segment.ms with 3 days in ms.  Is that so?